# Restful URI from Rails Tutorial Demo app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, url, rest

From the originall rail tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#sec-a_user_tour

URIs designed as followings

```
/microposts
/microposts/1
```

Now consider if you want to organize each micropost into exactly **ONE** categorie (name is unique), what URI you will perfer?

```
/categories
/categories/123
/categories/jewelries
/categories/123/jewelries
/categories/jewelries/123
```

or singular counterparts

```
/categories
/categories/123
/categories/jewelry
/categories/123/jewelry
/categories/jewelry/123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naming ReST resources is mostly a matter of taste. Just keep them coherent. If you choose to name `/categories` to serve a list of category, choose `/jewelries` to serve a list of jewelry.

I prefer using singular, `/category` for a list of category, `/category/123` for one category. You can use singular or plural as long as every resource follow the same rule.

Comment: But seems plural is the defecto standard in RoR? e.g. from the demo app they use `users`, `microposts` etc..

Comment: I'm not familiar with RoR, but IMO webservices are meant to be consumed by any client, so their naming convention is more a matter of company standards / developer taste.